# how to test fallback using react testing library

Tags: fallback, react-testing-library, react-suspense

I'm looking for a way to test a React.Suspense fallback using react-testing-library.  Consider this example:

```
const MyLazyThing = lazy(() => import('./index'));

export default function MyThing(props) {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="loading...">
      <MyLazyThing {...props} />
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

using `getByText('loading...')` doesn't seem to work.  wondering if there's a good way to test this in RTL.

thx

Comment: Have you tried mocking React.Lazy to prevent it from loading the component? Something kind of like `jest.spyOn(React, 'lazy').mockImplementation(() => () => false)`

Comment: I would add though that this test is a bit unnecessary. You're making a test to test that Suspense and Lazy work. It's generally safe to assume that React's features work.

Comment: Disagree. It would be useful to test, if the right fallback is shown.